# In airport check-in, some airlines weigh carry-on bags. If the bag is too heavy due to food that will be consumed in the airport, is that okay?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, low-cost-carriers

I flew recently and when getting the ticket at the check in stand, they weighed my carry on. It was underweight so everything was fine. Later when boarding the flight they did not weight the bags again, so anything I bought at the duty free was fine.

Sometimes I bring food with me to eat during my ~3 hours at the airport. If I am travelling with the family, the food can weight quite a bit. Due to the recent issues with receiving the check in luggage, I would prefer to fly only with carry on and carefully fill it to the max.

What would happen if during check-in my bag was too heavy, but I planned on eating and lightening it before boarding? Will they refuse to give me my boarding pass?

(now an absurd followup question)
Assuming that the above excuse is good, I noticed that they did not weight my bag at boarding. If I was grossly overweight with, what I (falsely) claimed to be kilograms of food, would I be able to use the same excuse?

Comment: I think this depends on the mood of the check-in staff...

Comment: Note that many forms of food will not be allowed through security.

Comment: @jcaron , thanks for that information. Most of my airport food is bland generic stuff. But I will make sure that it is allowed to go through security

Comment: Food you can eat in 3 hours will not weigh multiple kilograms, so I assume most of the weight is from packaging or maybe utensils. Any abnormal food packaging is likely to be relevant to the question (e.g. a kilogram jar of pickles?)

Comment: I can say that, in the US, I've never had my carry-on bag weighed, ever. Checked baggage, yes, but then they take it away so I'm not eating any food out of it.

Comment: @jcaron Such as??

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- anything with liquid (or liquid-ish) in it

Comment: split the food between passengers

Comment: If you eat the food, that weight is still going onto the plane.

Comment: If you're not visibly straining under the weight of your massive snack bag I should think you're okay all the way to your destination 99.9% of time.

Comment: Probably depends at least in part on the airline.  These days US domestic flights for the major airlines usually overlook a second carry-on that contains food as they no longer supply meals, so carrying the food in a separate bag through check in & security would be acceptable.  I would suggest a separate bag for the food anyway - you can always explain that that is for airport consumption & the check-in agent can take a quick look and see that it really is food.  But no guarantees.

Comment: Need to remember, the check-in staff have no guarantee that you will actually eat the fod before getting on the plane.

Comment: @Dragonel No food on domestic flights?  People must be bringing lots of food when flying from Boston to Honolulu, apparently an 11 hour flight.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- In the case of the US: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/food mostly restrictions on volume or anything liquid or liquid-like, but there are special instructions on a number of other items. Rules elsewhere may be different (though usually more or less similar).

Comment: @gerrit - They may provide the option to purchase food (although a lot of that disappeared in the pandemic) and will provide drinks & mini snacks.   These days Delta at least seems to do it by mileage flown https://www.delta.com/us/en/travel-planning-center/know-before-you-go/food-services-amenities.

Answer (score 10):

> What would happen if during check-in my bag was too heavy, but I planned on eating and lightening it before boarding? Will they refuse to give me my boarding pass?

The comment by Sabine is right:

> This depends on the mood of the check-in staff.

The worst that can reasonably happen is that they tell you your carry-on bag is too heavy.  Then you can take out all the food.  They will weigh it again and accept it.  Then you can put the food back in ;-).  Or you have to eat it all before returning to the check-in desk.  Just try to avoid it all ending up in the airplane sick bag…

Comment: The worst that will happen is that you have to eat your food before the check-in desk.

Comment: I would just carry it separately.  If security won't allow it through, step aside and eat it.  If it's out of the bag, its weight isn't an issue.